# Differences in numba outputs

Tags: python, numpy, numba

I implemented a basic nearest-neighbors search in my study work.
The fact is that the basic numpy implementation is working well, but just adding the '@jit' decorator (compiling in Numba), the outputs are differents (it duplicates some neighbors in the end for some unknown reason...)

Here is the basic algorithm:

```
import numpy as np
from numba import jit

@jit(nopython=True)
def knn(p, points, k):
    '''Find the k nearest neighbors (brute force) of the point p
    in the list points (each row is a point)'''

    n = p.size  # Lenght of the points
    M = points.shape[0]  # Number of points
    neighbors = np.zeros((k,n))
    distances = 1e6*np.ones(k)

    for i in xrange(M):
        d = 0
        pt = points[i, :]  # Point to compare
        for r in xrange(n):  # For each coordinate
            aux = p[r] - pt[r]
            d += aux * aux
        if d < distances[k-1]:  # We find a new neighbor
            pos = k-1
            while pos>0 and d<distances[pos-1]:  # Find the position
                pos -= 1
            pt = points[i, :]
            # Insert neighbor and distance:
            neighbors[pos+1:, :] = neighbors[pos:-1, :]
            neighbors[pos, :] = pt
            distances[pos+1:] = distances[pos:-1]
            distances[pos] = d

    return neighbors, distances
```

For testing:

```
p = np.random.rand(10)
points = np.random.rand(250, 10)
k = 5
neighbors = knn(p, points, k)
```

WITHOUT the @jit decorator, one gets the correct answer:

```
In [1]: distances
Out[1]: array([ 0.3933974 ,  0.44754336,  0.54548715,  0.55619749,  0.5657846 ])
```

But the Numba compilation gives weird outputs:

```
Out[2]: distances
Out[2]: array([ 0.3933974 ,  0.44754336,  0.54548715,  0.54548715,  0.54548715])
```

Somebody can help? I don't realize why it happens...

Thanks you.

Comment: You may be interested in the scipy [KDTree](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.cKDTree.html) implementation.

Comment: @Ophion Thanks for the tip. I've been playing with the KDTree implementation of sklearn (I suppose they are similar) and they are good for preprocessing the data for future multiples query points. In my work, I need to find the neighbors changing the points list all the time (in image processing stuff), and this type of implementations become too slow. And it seems that the KDTree implementation is not better than brute force when the space dimension is large (larger than 25 for example).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the issue is that Numba is handling writing one slice into another differently when those slices are overlapping than when running without. I'm not familiar with the internals of numpy, but perhaps there is special logic to handle dealing with volatile memory operations like this, that aren't there in Numba. Change the following lines and the results with the jit decorator become consistent with the plain python version:

```
neighbors[pos+1:, :] = neighbors[pos:-1, :].copy()
...
distances[pos+1:] = distances[pos:-1].copy()
```

Comment: Thanks @JoshAdel !
This works for me. I verified before that this overlapping slice in Numpy doesn't cause problems, but for some reasons Numba translates it into a different algorithm...
In all cases, it's weard that only duplicates some of the neighbors but not the others...
Thanks again!
PD: I'm a fan of python, but things like that makes me think seriously to learn Julia...

Comment: @MarioGonzález I would encourage you to post your example as an issue on the Numba github issue tracker. The dev team is usually very responsive and want to know about bugs or unexpected behavior.

Comment: Thanks @JoshAdel for the advice. It was posted [here](https://github.com/numba/numba/issues/1960).